# Is there a way to post to a local IP address from a hosted site with Django python?

Tags: python, django, lan

I have a controller that has APIs only accessible on my local network, with a local address of, say, 10.0.1.7.  When I host Django on my local network (http://127.0.0.1:8000/), I am able to successfully post to the controller APIs.  However, when I host the site externally (let's call it www.djangolan.com), the post does not execute.  I would like to know if there is a way to configure the settings/permissions such that when a post is made from the site www.djangolan.com, while my machine is connected to the LAN, that it is able to execute.

```
def user_created(request):
    contents = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            firstName = form.cleaned_data['firstName']
            lastName = form.cleaned_data['lastName']

            url = "http://adminname:password@10.0.1.7/api/"

            fullName = lastName + " , " + firstName

            createUserJSON = {"SetUser":
              {"User": [{
                  "Name": fullName,
                  "Description": "",
                  "Attribute": [
                        {
                          "type": "",
                          "Name": "FirstName",
                          "Value": firstName
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "",
                            "Name": "LastName",
                            "Value": lastName
                        }
                   ]
                }]
              }
            }
            r = requests.post(url,json=createUserJSON)
     return render(request,'user_created.html',contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

The IP that you are using is a private or an internal IP. It is an IP relative only known to your private network i.e. your LAN.

When you host the site on a public domain, the API also needs to be hosted on a public IP. So, you will have to figure out the public IP of your LAN and use that IP while connecting from an external network.

> A **public IP address** is the address that is assigned to a computing
>   device to allow direct access over the Internet. A web server, email
>   server and any server device directly accessible from the Internet are
>   candidate for a public IP address. A public IP address is globally
>   unique, and can only be assigned to a unique device.
>
> When a computer is assigned a **private IP address**, the local
>   devices see this computer via it's private IP address. However, the
>   devices residing outside of your local network cannot directly
>   communicate via the private IP address, but uses your router's public
>   IP address to communicate.

Reference: https://www.iplocation.net/public-vs-private-ip-address